# Rmarkdown with LaTex-document in appendix?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I need to create an Rmarkdown document in which I have some text and 3 appendices showing 3 different LaTex files. I found many resources showing how to append Rcode in an appenidx, but have been unsuccessful for other kinds of appendices. As a structure, I use a [thesisdown-template](https://github.com/ismayc/thesisdown). The template has several chapters that are all compiled together in the end. There is also an appendix-template but I haven't figured out how to include a LaTex file in there. But given that I can have LaTex code in a Markdown file, it should be possible?

I do not need to use thesis-down, it could also be similar to the following:
[image]

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then you are only interested in PDF output. You can embed raw LaTeX commands in R Markdown, so the following should do what you need:

```
\appendix

## Appendix 1

\input{/path/to/my/LaTeXfile.tex}

## Appendix 2

\input{/path/to/my/other/LaTeXfile.tex}
```